# BigDecimal in JSTL, divide by int or double returns integer

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el, bigdecimal

```
<fmt:formatNumber var="instAmount" value="${invoice.amount / offer.getTotalInstallments()}" minFractionDigits="2" />
```

Where amount is `BigDecimal` in `Java` and `totalInstallments` is `int`. I tried by setting `totalInstallments` to `double` but nothing changes. It returns an `Integer`, it behaves as when you divide two integers in Java, you get an integer.

Am I missing something or is there a workaround?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Works just fine for me on Tomcat 7. What JSTL impl/version and servletcontainer impl/version are you using? Perhaps some older JSTL or EL version didn't properly support BigDecimal.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution is to just do this calculation in the controller/servlet and use the result on the view page. I think calculations should be done in the controller and not the view. You would use the divide() method on the BigDecimal.

That said, if you do want to do this in the view you have to define a JSTL function in a tag library and create a static version of divide which accepts the BigDecimal and the int you are diving by.

Comment: Yes i'm implementing a custom function, I know about the logic/calculation should be done in Java, it's just that my scenario is such that it's more appropriate this way, and I will only use it as 'read-only' stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
< fmt:parseNumber value="${invoice.amount}" var="a" />

< fmt:parseNumber value="${offer.value)}"  var="b" />

${a/b}
```